Analog of Payley-Wiener theorem for Schwartz distributions with support in the half-line
Let $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ denote the Schwartz class of (Fourier transformable) distributions on $\mathbb{R}$, and denote the Fourier transform by $\widehat{\cdot}$.
Let
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
{\mathcal{S}}'({\mathbb{R}}_+)
\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!\{f\in {\mathcal{S}}'(\mathbb{R})\;|\; \text{supp}(f)\subset [0,\infty)\},\\
 {\mathbb{H}}\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!\{z\in \mathbb{C}\;|\; \text{Im}(z)>0\},\\
 \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{H})\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\! 
\{F:\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{C}\;|\;F\text{ is holomorphic on }\mathbb{H}\},\\
 \mathcal{A}\!\!\!\!&=&\!\!\!\!\{F\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{H})\;|\; \exists M>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }
\forall z\in \mathbb{H}, |f(z)|\le M(1+|z|)^N\}.
\end{array}
$$
Are the following two claims true?

If $f\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}_+)$, then there exists an $F\in \mathcal{A}$  such that $F(\cdot+iy)\to \widehat{f}$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ as $y\to 0+$.
If $F\in \mathcal{A}$, then the limit of $F(\cdot +iy)$ as $y\to 0+$ exists in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, and is equal to the Fourier transform of some element in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}_+)$.


(2) looks correct to me. We can write $F(z)=(z+i)^{N+1}G(z)$ with $G\in H^2$, so $\widehat{F}$ should be a convolution of $\widehat{G}\in L^2(0,\infty)$ and $\delta$'s and $\delta'$'s.

Thank you. Yes, you are right, I found an article by Suwa and Yoshino (2004, J. Math. Sci. Univ. Tokyo), from which it seems that for equivalence, the appropriate algebra $\mathcal{A}$ consists of those holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{H}$ that satisfy an estimate of the form $|F(z)|\le M (1+|z|)^N (1+|\text{Im}(z)|^{-N})$ for all $z\in \mathbb{H}$.
